# Can pi be written as algebraic+log(algebraic)?

Tags: pi, transcendental-numbers

The [Universal parabolic constant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/universal_parabolic_constant) is "the ratio between the arc length of the parabolic segment formed by the latus rectum to the focal parameter". It can be seen as '$\pi$ but for parabola'.

The universal parabolic constant can be shown to be equal to $\ln(1+\sqrt{2})+\sqrt{2}$. This is a transcendental number, but it is the sum of an algebraic number and the log of an algebraic number. I think that almost all real numbers are not of that form.

No such simple representation is known for the "universal circle constant" $\pi$ (at least not to me), but has this already been proven?

More formally: do there exist $a,b\in \mathbb{R}$, such that $\pi = a+\ln b$, and $a$ and $b$ are both algebraic?

Comment: Conjecturally no, see [this related MO-post](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/118523/is-pi-log-ab-for-some-integers-a-b-1). It is related to Shanuel's conjecture.

Comment: I guess $-i\ln(-1)$ does not work?

Comment: @TymaGaidash This is a product , not a sum.

Comment: @DietrichBurde: I'd accept that as an answer!